# screencast-o-matic keyboard shortcuts - I can't get them to work

Tags: java, shortcuts, openjdk, screencast

I switched to ubuntu a few months ago and I have not yet been able to understand why Screencast-o-Matic keyboard shortcuts don't work.

Apparently they should work on ubuntu in the same way as on Windows, but they don't at least for me.

I am on 13.04 and everything runs great.
When I try the ALT+P shortcut nothing happens.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you very much!

```
$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_25-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.25-b01, mixed mode)
```

I had the openJDK and it did not work so I thought of trying oracle, still no go.
I noticed that when I select the SOM recorder window the unity menu panel on top left says "Firefox" perhaps this has to do with the issue?

Comment: Could you edit your question and provide what version of Java are you using?

Comment: Thank you very much @Braiam, edited the question with additional details

Comment: @Braiam do you have any suggestion? thank you